# How can I properly forecast sales with skewed data?

Tags: r, forecasting, predictive-models

I'm using model trees to forecast sales data. I've developed a pretty good model but I'm concerned about some of the models predictions. I'm working with R and using the M5P algo in the RWeka package.

I'm forecasting revenues so I never have negative numbers but my model predicts negative numbers. That makes me think I'm doing something incorrectly. Here is the shape of my data[image]

What should I do to make sure my model doesn't predict meaningless values?

Comment: describe your data. what's sample size? sampling frequency? some time series graphs etc.

Comment: Negative numbers can be forecasted because there is no embedded logic to restrict that from happening.AUTOBOX a piece of software I wrote simply allows that unless a control file called POSITIVE.AFS exists which acts as a truncater. Similar things happen when you have a history of integers and the forecast delivered is xx.yyy . I wouldn't worry about the existence of negative forecasts but I would adjust them. If you post your data I will be glad to show you how to proceed or at least how I would proceed with the tools that I have on hand.

Comment: There are hourly observations. Sorry I'm not cool enough to make graphs in R yet. That said, it's pretty cyclical. It's not a sample It's 3 years worth of data which is the total dataset.

Comment: Min. 0
1st Qu. 15.5
Median 52.6
Mean 71.80738
3rd Qu. 104.5
Max.  299.86

Comment: If it's just a matter of writing some logic so I don't get negative numbers then problem solved. I was more concerned about using an inappropriate distribution or the wrong modeling technique. For instance this summer I had to create a forecast of how much a project was going to cost. I started with a normal curve but got better results when I switched to a Poisson. That said, I don't think a Poisson would work here because we're talking about a continuous value and not integer counts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility for modeling continuous nonnegative data is the gamma distribution. You can include covariates by running a gamma regression, e.g., using [`glm()`](http://pj.freefaculty.org/guides/stat/Regression-GLM/Gamma/GammaGLM-01.pdf). Since you have time series, you may want to create harmonics or (Gaussian or other) dummies as predictors to model seasonalities.

Then again, your data seems to have a suspicious bump at zero. This would argue for a [Tweedie distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tweedie_distribution), which is a kind of "zero-inflated gamma distribution". You can run a "Tweedie regression" in R by using the [`Tweedie`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tweedie/tweedie.pdf) and the [`statmod`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/statmod/statmod.pdf) packages.

I don't know whether you could model autoregressive behavior in some reasonable way. Then again, you may not even need it if you use useful regressors.

Comment: Mr. Kolassa, I also have one time series which is right-skewed as the amount of sales dropped significantly through time. May I ask if we could use arima models to fit this kind of cases as I get a very good result in `Ljung-Box` test and every thing looks ok.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR: the overall distribution is not very important. If you have promotions, you might even have a multimodal overall distribution - but if you can model the peaks with predictors, everything is fine. So yes, ARIMA can be used to model sales that drop over time. (I am not a big fan of ARIMA in any case.)

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Kolassa, I appreciate your response.